# Temporarily suspend data-binding in AngularJS to update model without firing $scope.$watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

**UPDATE 4/19/2012 12PM PST:** Gotta eat crow on this one. The problem was not with Angular's databinding but with math errors in how I was calculating the dates. I wasn't properly taking into account the minutes and seconds in my time calculations. I was just subtracting the timestamps from each other expecting the hours to come out nicely.

---

I've gotten myself into trouble with AngularJS databinding in which my different inputs need to be reciprocally bound to each other.

The form needs to contain the following:

1. A start date (this is a given, not an input)
2. An input to add hours on to the start date
3. Two inputs with the result: 1) a date picker and 2) an hour picker

If you change any of the inputs, it should update the others. So, the following would be desirable results:

1. (with original date-time as April 19th at 10pm). User enters '1 hour'. The result date becomes April 19th and the result time becomes 11pm.
2. Building on the above example, the user changes the date input to April 20th. The 'hours' now become 25 hours.

I've placed set up watchers, using `$scope.$watch` on each of these variables:

```
$scope.$watch('hours', function (newHours, oldHours, scope) {
  if (newHours) {
    var newEndDate = new Date(scope.origDate),
      offHours = newEndDate.getHours();    

    newEndDate.setHours(offHours + newHours);
    scope.endDate = newEndDate;
    scope.endHours = newEndDate.getHours();
  }
});    


$scope.$watch('endHours', function (newEndHours, oldEndHours, scope) {
  if (newEndHours) {
    var newEndDate = new Date(scope.endDate);
    newEndDate.setHours(newEndHours);    

    scope.endDate = newEndDate;
  }
});    

$scope.$watch('endDate', function (newEndDate, oldEndDate, scope) {
  if (newEndDate) {
    scope.hours = (newEndDate - scope.origDate) / (1000  * 60 * 60);
  }
});
```

Each of these works fine on their own, but in tandem they cause a big fat mess. From my understanding of Angular, it seems that they're creating a 'feedback loop.' **Edit**: To wit, model 'A' will be updated and trigger a change on model 'B'. Model 'B' will then trigger a change on model 'A'.

**Now**, is it possible to temporarily suspend data-binding so that I can *just* update the models without firing the watchers? In some other contexts I've worked in (UITableView on Cocao comes to mind), one can ask to "stop updates," make some changes to the model, and then "resume updates."

Is there anything like this in AngularJS? If not, what am I not getting here, and how could I set up my project to achieve the desired functionality?

Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/m2vl5swRSd0iszBeZQXn) of my example.

Comment: Could you explain the "big fat mess" and the "feedback loop" ?

Comment: @ganaraj : Control 'A' will update control 'B' which, in turn, updates control 'A'.

Comment: Angular is smart in this regard. If Control A (instance1) triggers Control B and Control B trigger's Control A ( instance2 ) then if instance1 and instance2 are one and the same then angular doesnt again trigger ControlB. So you dont have to worry about it. If this loop keeps happening then you will get "Exceeded digest cycle error" in your console.

Comment: @ganaraj: this has been my experience in most cases, but if you look at the update of the plnkr (with the console open) you'll see that updating the 'End Date' controller triggers an update on the model three times. In the midst of these changes, the data is corrupted. The exact nature of this corruption is that the resulting date is not the one the user selects from the date input.